# Does there exist a formal set-theoretic definition of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, recreational-mathematics

In mathematics, there are many objects that can be defined purely in terms of sets (e.g. $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ for ordered pairs, among others). I was wondering if there is a purely set-theoretic definition of a matrices. For example, how could one define the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 &\pi \\ \cos{(3)} & 33 &0\end{bmatrix}$$
purely in terms of sets? Many thanks.

Comment: Set theory is the logical foundation for almost every area of math (except category theory), so basically all objects you'll encounter in an undergraduate math curriculum have formal definitions as sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remembering having the same question back in the day and I came up with the following definition.

A matrix is just a function of the form $A:I\times J\to R$ where $R$ is a ring.
We usually take $I=\{1,\dots,n\}$, $J=\{1,\dots,m\}$ and write $A_{ij}$ instead of $A(i,j)$.

Comment: I'd say we always make those choices of $I$ and $J$ in the definition of a matrix.

Comment: Oh, I see. So would the above matrix be defined as the function

$$A \quad \begin{array}{|ccc}
\{1,2\} \times \{1,2,3\} &\longrightarrow &\mathbb{R} \\
(i,j) &\longmapsto &A_{ij}
\end{array}$$

with 

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
A(1,1)=1 & A(1,2)=3 & A(1,3)=\pi \\
A(2,1)=\cos{(3)} & A(2,2)=33 & A(2,3)=0
\end{bmatrix}$$

is that correct? Have I correctly understood your comment?

Comment: @Zak1120 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Oh, I see. This is much clearer, now. Very nice!